Measuring the thermal resistance of a window
I would like to compare the R-value (thermal resistance) of several windows in my house. Is there a simple experiment I can do, with home equipment, to measure it with reasonable accuracy?

I would try to borrow a infrared camera and heat the rooms to the same temperature.

@trula I searched online for IR cameras and found a very large variety - what kind of IR camera exactly do I need for this? And how exactly would I use it for measuring the R-value?

In order to get the gross resistance, seal the window from outside tightly at the frame with a box of foamed polystyrene, fill a flat container with a fixed mass of boiling water. Measure the water temperature continously until the temperature difference to inside is halved.
$$ T(t)= 20 +(100-20)  \  e^{-\lambda  t}, \quad  e^{- \lambda t_{1/2}} = \frac{1}{2} $$
Glass is black in the infrared, so the result can be used to compare the low temperature transport coefficients in units $\frac {J}{s \ m^2}$ by the fixed heat capacity difference of water with $\frac{1\text{ kcal}}{kg\ (\Delta K)} $
